# How to show opening balance and closing balance without cursor or recursive

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table which has the following columns:

```
Id
Transdate
OpeningBalance
Debit
Credit
ClosingBalance
```

I would like to output this:

```
OpeningBalance   Debit    Credit   ClosingBalance
-------------------------------------------------
      0          100        0         100
    100                    50          50
     50          300                  350
```

Comment: how about a clear question, so we know what you want...  looks like a simple query like SELECT OpeningBalance,Debit,Credit,ClosingBalance FROM YourTable would do the trick, and that can't be all you need to know, right?

Comment: i explain all detail and I want to calculate closing stock and last closing stock next opening stock how

Answer (score 0):

This generates the output as shown in your question

```
SELECT OpeningBalance,Debit,Credit,ClosingBalance FROM YourTable
```

Does this work? If not, why?

Do you also want sums? Like sum of a day? You should try to be more specific and precise in your question.